# Decompress compressed string with Huffman algorithm

Tags: delphi, huffman-code

I am trying to use Huffman algorithm from http://www.explainth.at/downloads/huff.zip

There are two function in the unit :

function Compress(ASource:TMemoryStream):TMemoryStream;
function DeCompress(ASource:TMemoryStream):TMemoryStream;

I've successfully compressed each lines from a file onto an another file.

```
function StreamToString(const stream: TStream) : string;
var
Size: Integer;
begin
  result:='';
  Size := Stream.Size - Stream.Position;
  SetString(result, nil, Size);
  Stream.Read(Pointer(result)^, Size);
end;
procedure TMaster.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
list,list_:TStringlist;
AStream:TMemoryStream;
BStream:TMemoryStream;
s:string;
i,j:integer;
begin
  list := TStringList.Create;
  list_:= TStringList.Create;
  list.LoadFromFile('d:\input.txt');

  for j := 0 to List.Count - 1 do
  begin
    s:=list[j];
    if (Length(s) = 0) then exit;
    {i:=Pos(#13#10,s);
    while (i > 0) do
    begin
      Delete(s,i,2);
      i:=Pos(#13#10,s);
    end;}

    AStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
    with AStream do WriteBuffer(s[1],Length(s));
    with THuffman.Create do
    try
      BStream:=Compress(AStream);
    finally
      Free;
      AStream.Free;
    end;

  with THuffman.Create do
  try
    AStream:=ProcessToDecrypt (BStream);
    list_.Add(StreamToString(BStream));
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end
  end; //for j := 0 to List.Count - 1 do

  list_.SaveToFile('d:\output.txt');
  list_.free;
  list.free; 
end;

function THuffman.ProcessToDecrypt(ASource:TMemoryStream):TMemoryStream;
var ASize:Integer;
begin
  ASize:=ReBuildTree(ASource);
  exit;
end;
```

I also want to decompress each compressed line from a file to string.

Here's what I done to decompress the string

```
procedure TMaster.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var i:Integer;
    AText:String;
    AStream:TMemoryStream;
    BStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  AText:='È1ëz-';
  BStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;

  with BStream do WriteBuffer(AText[1],Length(AText));

  with THuffman.Create do
  try
    AStream:=ProcessToDecrypt (BStream);
    AStream:=Decompress(BStream); 
    memoOut.Lines.add.StreamToString(BStream);
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Button2Click procedure doesn't work. <s>The short question is how do I decompress the compressed **string**?</s>

The parameter of DeCompress is TMemoryStream, <s>How do I use a string as the parameter?</s>
How to make the output of DeCompress as string?

Comment: Why are you compressing each line individually (creating a THuffman, compressing and freeing)? This sounds like the likely cause, i.e. the resulting stream is actually a series of streams concatenated together so when you come to decompress you don't know where each compressed line starts and ends.

Comment: @John, I agree that's the right answer. Move the comment down.

Comment: @John, First, sorry for my bad English. Actually I want to make a database that contains compressed string. Next, my program will load each line onto an array. Button2Click doesn't represent decompress for each compressed line. My question is how do I decompress a compressed string?

Comment: I want to rearrange my question. The parameter of DeCompress is TMemoryStream, How do I use a string as the parameter?

Comment: (I assume pre unicode Delphi versions, since in D2009+ this code will go wrong)  The current way of copying a string into a memory stream looks fine. There is also a TStringStream IIRC, but I never use it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my comments above, just looking at your code, the value in AText is likely not a correct representation of the compressed string. The following very simple program (based on yours) works:

```
uses Huffman;

procedure TForm1.UncompressButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AStream:TMemoryStream;
  BStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  BStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  with BStream do LoadFromFile('c:\temp\in.txt');

  with THuffman.Create do
  try
    AStream:=Decompress(BStream);
    AStream.SaveToFile('c:\temp\out.txt');
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.CompressButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  AText:String;
  AStream:TMemoryStream;
  BStream:TMemoryStream;
begin
  AText := Edit1.Text;
  BStream:=TMemoryStream.Create;
  with BStream do WriteBuffer(AText[1],Length(AText));
  with THuffman.Create do
  try
    AStream:=Compress(BStream);
    AStream.SaveToFile('c:\temp\in.txt');
  finally
    BStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's not what I mean. Let's say I have encrypted string. I just want to decrypt the encrypted string onto a string.

Comment: It won't work via a string as the compressed string contains null (char 0). Basically a string cannot represent every possible array of characters. [Sorry for my earlier mix up of compress / decompress and encryt / decrypt]

Comment: Wow, that is really a bad news for me :(

Comment: Why do you need to pass the compressed (binary) data around as a string? You spoke earlier of using a database. I assume you are trying to store the compressed text in a varchar or similar. Does your database support BLOBs? If so, these will be a more appropriate way of storing binary data.

Comment: This is a plain text database. For example my data are 'aaaaa', 'bbbbb' and many more. Each data(=string) is separated by line. My program will load all lines from the plain text into an array. That's why I need to compress each line of string. So my database size is smaller and my program consume less memory.

Comment: You could Base64 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64 encode/decode additionally to your Huffman encoding/decoding.